# Remove-AzSqlDatabaseDataMaskingRule is ignoring Table and Column name

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-powershell

PowerShell method `Remove-AzSqlDatabaseDataMaskingRule` acts as if it has undefined behaviour.

It seems to completely disregard the `-TableName` and `-ColumnName` parameters and simply remove the first masking rule it finds instead.

See the following command:

`Remove-AzSqlDatabaseDataMaskingRule -SchemaName "dbo" -TableName "anything" -ColumnName "anything" -ServerName "our-server-name" -DatabaseName "our-database-name" -ResourceGroupName "our-rg"`

Calling

`Get-AzSqlDatabaseDataMaskingRule -ServerName "our-server-name" -DatabaseName "our-database-name" -ResourceGroupName "our-rg"`

Returns all rules before the remove command, and it returns one less after the remove command. So it removes something, just the specific rule we ask it to.

Anyone familiar with this behaviour?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I can also reproduce your issue on my side, even with the latest `Az.Sql` module, it should be a bug.

In this case, my workaround is to use [`Invoke-AzRestMethod`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.accounts/invoke-azrestmethod?view=azps-5.2.0) to call the REST API - [`Data Masking Rules - Create Or Update`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/sql/datamaskingrules/createorupdate) directly.
Make sure your `Az` module is not too old, otherwise there is no `Invoke-AzRestMethod` command, you could use `Update-Module -Name Az` to update the module if necessary.

In my sample, `tab1` is the *TableName*, `col2` is the *ColumnName*, `dbo` is the *SchemaName*, also replace them with your values, `"ruleState": "Disabled"` is used to remove the rule. For the details about the values in the `Payload`, you could use `Get-AzSqlDatabaseDataMaskingRule` to see a specific one.

```
$id = (Get-AzSqlDatabase -ServerName "joysqldb" -DatabaseName "joydb1" -ResourceGroupName "xxxx").ResourceId

Invoke-AzRestMethod -Path "$id/dataMaskingPolicies/Default/rules/dbo_tab1_col2?api-version=2014-04-01" -Method "PUT" -Payload '{
  "properties": {
    "id": "dbo_tab1_col2",
    "ruleState": "Disabled",
    "schemaName": "dbo",
    "tableName": "tab1",
    "columnName": "col2",
    "maskingFunction": "Default"
  }
}'
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for investigating! I've opened an issue in their GitHub.